# How to delay a loop in a generator function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-6, yield

I have written a small generator that simply enumerates a bunch of messages I handed over to it:

```
'use strict';

const sequential = function * (messages) {
  for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    yield messages[i];
  }
};

module.exports = sequential;
```

I use it like this:

```
for (const message of sequential(messages)) {
  // Do something to message...
}
```

Basically, everything works fine. Now I want the generator to delay the `yield` calls, e.g. for 100 milliseconds.

The problem is that I can not simply introduce a `setTimeout` call, as otherwise the `yield` is not contained any longer in a generator function, but a normal callback.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want to delay it by 100 ms though you're going to need *some* kind of callback method. Javascript doesn't play nicely with synchronous thread blocking. Could you meet somewhere in the middle and have your generator function yield a `Promise` of a `message` which is then subscribed to in your `// Do something to the message...` block?

Comment: Or, use a recursive function that calls the generator once every 100 ms.

Comment: Since *synchronous* code is using the generator, the only way to delay is to *block synchronously*, which means your entire thread will be blocked. If you need asynchronous delays the calling code needs to accommodate asynchronous calls. Though really, it seems odd to me that the generator is delaying in the first place. The *consumer* of the generator should have a say over timing if necessary, not the generator.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, this solvd it :-). If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: It would be more interesting if you posted your actual solution and accepted it yourself, but glad it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *synchronous* code is using the generator, the only way to delay is to *block synchronously*, which means your entire thread will be blocked. If you need asynchronous delays the calling code needs to accommodate asynchronous calls. Though really, it seems odd to me that the generator is delaying in the first place. The *consumer* of the generator should have a say over timing if necessary, not the generator.

Comment: I solved it using an asynchronous loop using the `async` module. The hint to delay at the caller, not the callee, did it :-)